# Rotate a scale vector

Tags: vectors

I have a rectangle $R$ that is rotated by angle $\theta$, and a scaling vector $\vec s$ that is to be applied to $R$. However, $\vec s$ does not take into account $\theta$ and so when I try to scale $R$, I get an incorrect result. For example, if $\vec s=\langle1.1,1.0\rangle$ and $\theta = \pi/2$, then I actually want to scale the rectangle by $\langle1.0,1.1\rangle$. At first I tried this in order to transform $\vec s$: $$abs(rotate(\vec s-\langle1,1\rangle, \theta))+\langle1,1\rangle$$

This works, but only as long as both components of $\vec s$ are greater than 1. If one of them is 0.9 for example, it is transformed into 1.1 by this equation, resulting in incorrect scaling. How do I correctly orient $\vec s$ according to $\theta$?

Comment: Why not simply scale the rectangle before rotating it? That would give the correct result for the one example that you’ve given.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute value. If $\vec{s}=\langle0.9,1\rangle$ and $\theta=\pi/2$, when you rotate $\vec{s}-\langle1,1\rangle$ you get $\langle0,-0.1\rangle$. If you add $\langle1,1\rangle$ you get $\langle1,0.9\rangle$. Also note to check if you need to rotate the scaling vector by $\theta$ or by $-\theta$